# Is it possible to roll-up summarize child records based on a lookup field?

Tags: workflow, roll-up-summary

I'm not sure whether this works or whether I'm doing something wrong so here goes:
I want to have a COUNT rollup summary field that summarizes opportunity products that have a value in a lookup field.  If I set the COUNT to summarize products where this field does not equal '' (ie. empty) it's always set as 0, even though one or more products do have a value in that field.  Is this just a limitation of roll-up summary fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Salesforce documentation:

> You can’t use long text area, multi-select picklist, Description
>   fields, system fields like Last Activity, cross-object formula fields,
>   and lookup fields in the field column of roll-up summary filters.

So what you want is not natively possible in Salesforce.

You can use this workaroud.

1. Create a new field on you child object named as "Duplicate Lookup Text" of  type Text
2. Create a Workflow Rule, Created and Edited to subsequently meet the criteria, and criteria being the Lookup Field is not null
3. Create a Rollup- Summary on Parent Object for Count and use the filter criteria as Duplicate Lookup Text is not null

   [image: Select Roll-Up Type]

Voila Done.

Src: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=5

Comment: how about DLRS?

Comment: @cropredy that came to my mind, but as I am not writing code and using standard SF functionality I didnt bother. If it gets more messier, DLRS is the way forward

Comment: N.B. DLRS does not require writing any code and avoids the WFR

Comment: Agreed.........

Comment: Thanks Pranay,  your solution is the easiest way to accomplish this.  I've been looking into DLRS and will defo find a way using that in the future!  Have some points on me for your help :)